# How to make users feel comfortable signing/authorizing legal documents online?

Tags: usability, forms, user-behavior, user-expectation, users

I'm struggling to find UI/UX examples where the user is prompted to click a button and do something legally binding or something very significant and important - such as sign a contract, agree to loan, etc.

I can't seem to find any articles written about this UX problem either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose it depends upon how legally binding and what the consumer motivation and expectation was. For instance when I had my wood floors done the company sent over an email in which in had to sign that I authorized the job and that someone would be there at the agreed time and place.  It did not bother me a second. In fact I thought more highly of them for doing this. Mind you my contractual obligation was minimal - I agree to the job and price and promised to have an adult there to let them in.

Comment: But should you feel 'comfortable' doing something legally binding / very significant and important?

Answer (score 1):

Try googling *digital signature verification software*. Adobe has a system that has a 14-day free trial that you could use to get hands on and there are many others.   What they have in common is a third party that is both in on the signature, possibly the identity of the signatory, and probably the document contents, but you should be able to get some UX insight.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the legislation in your country, you can leave out a lot of painful steps during the sign-up process. For insurance for example, you only need very basic details, like personal data, house information and the users' preferences in coverage. Users can be guided in quick steps and depending on your brand, you can even enrich the experience with some fun and animations. Users giving consent through checkboxes and clicking 'Agreed' is already enough to create a contract. Depending on legislation, they'll have a certain amount of time to cancel the contract if they wish.

Now, depending on the complexity of the product, you're either already done at this stage, or you'll need to ask the user to supply additional documents. This requirement (mainly for loans) makes the process a bit more painful. You can ease the process by showing users what documents are missing, which ones have already been uploaded and offer tools to make uploading easier. The biggest challenge when it comes to signing and uploading things online is trust. Users want to know for sure that, what they're doing is the right thing, and that they're benefiting. Use microcopy, social proof and persuasion design aspects wherever possible. By being transparent about the process, like what's to come and what the requirements of documents are, you instil a sense of ease.

The insurers and loan companies I've worked for have always offered their users a 'my environment' after their initial request has been processed. This means they can log in and supply documents and read more information in a secured environment. The contract is not set in place until they've completed this process, recieved their offer, and have signed it and re-uploaded the contract. Once this is done, the contract is set in place.

If you have access to legal, you may want to inquire how it works in your country and when a contract becomes binding. The user flow for requesting a loan or insurance is by no means different from a regular sales funnel. There's just more paper work and user effort involved. If you chunk your content in logical bits, show progress and guide the user, you can ease the pain in this process greatly.